# Optimising a [large] look-up table within a loop, in R

Tags: r, optimization, simulation, lookup

I would really appreciate any help in optimising the code below. For the number of iterations I need to run, it currently takes way to long.

Basically, I'm looking for the optimal set of model parameters for estimating a variable of interest. I'm simulating a set of model parameters and a variable of interest, using each of them (in a loop) to model the signal of interest, then compare each of the modeled signal to the observed signal, and where they are minimised select one of the (simulated) values we're trying to predict. Then, a RMSE function is used to select which set of model parameters offers the smallest error compared to the observed values.

Many Thanks

## Code

```
#Empty variable
 est_hold <- NULL

# Model Parameters (simulated and/or estimated via NLS earlier)
    beta <- seq(0.001,0.2,0.01)
    sig.g <- seq(0.028, 0.038,length.out = 20)
    sig.v <- seq(0.6, 0.8,length.out = 20)
    params <- data.frame(rbind(beta,sig.g,sig.v))

# Simulated variable of interest (Dependant variable)
sim_var <- seq(1,100,0.1)

# Observed signal (Independant variable)
obs_sig <- seq(0.0001,0.8,length.out = 100000)

# Observed variable of interest (Dependant variable)
obs_var2 <- seq(1,100,length.out = 100000)


min.func <- function(x) {sim_var[which.min(x)]}

system.time({
  for(c in 1:ncol(params)){

    # Modelled signal (Independant) 
    model_var <- params[2,c]*exp(-params[1,c]*sim_var)+params[3,c]*(1-exp(-params[1,c]*sim_var))

    # Calculate difference between each modelled value (using simulated params) and each observed value
    diff <- t(apply(as.data.frame(model_var),1,"-",obs_sig)) 
    diff <- abs(diff)

    # Apply function, to select a simulated dependant value where differences are minimised
    est <- apply(diff,2,min.func)
    rm(diff)

    est_hold <- cbind(est_hold,unlist(est))

  }})

# RMSE function, to calculate RMSE between observed dependant variable and the modelled dependant variable (using simulated params)
rmse.fun = function(x){sqrt(sum((obs_var2-x)^2)/length(obs_var2))}

# Apply the RMSE function to the matrix of modelled values 
# (where each column represents modelled values using each of the simulated params)
sim_rmse <- apply(est_hold,2,rmse.fun)

# Find the position of the lowest RMSE
ind <- which.min(sim_rmse)

#Use this position to subset the parameters (...and continue with script/modelling)
final_params <- params[ind]
```

Comment: the data.table package could be interesting for you,..

Comment: I'd recommend `profvis` package as a great way to see what the slowest part of the code is, so you can spend your time trying to fix that slowest bits first